# How I put same x-axis twice in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I want a very large plot on which will be very convinient to have the same axis top and bottom. Is there any simple way of duplicating the axis? Or I need to define a secondary axis but with the same range (I don´t like this solution because Bokeh computes the range of the axis on its own and I don´t want to re compute them)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to add extra axis to a plot in bokeh. You need to import your type of axis, here `LinearAxis` is used.

If you use `p.x_range` and `p.y_range` in the definition of your new axes, then they have the same range as the original ones.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import LinearAxis
output_notebook()

# some data
p = figure(width=300, height=300)
p.line(x=[1,2,3], y=[2,3,4])

# exta x axis
p.extra_x_ranges.update({'x_above':  p.x_range})
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(x_range_name='x_above'), 'above')
# exta y axis
p.extra_y_ranges.update({'y_right':  p.y_range})
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name='y_right'), 'right')

show(p)
```

[image: output]